# Crear tabla HTML con c# desde un datatable

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas tardes a todos.

Lo que necesito es crear una tabla HTML desde c#, los datos que necesito los tengo en un datatable, esto con el fin de enviar un correo electrónico desde una clase y en el cuerpo debe de ir una tabla.

Buscando en la web pude ver que se puede lograr creando una tabla de esta manera pero no sé como empezar, como comentario ya tengo creada mi clase para enviar el correo electrónico.

```
    string cuerpo = "";
    public DataTable Detalles;
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    public void EnviarCorreo(string correo_electronico)
    {            
        int NumeroFilas = Detalles.Rows.Count;
        cuerpo = "Se prestaron " + NumeroFilas + " dispositivos a su 
        nombre";
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new 
        System.Net.NetworkCredential("Direccion", "password");
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        mail = new MailMessage();
        try
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress("Direccion de envío", "Prestamo", 
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.Subject = "Prestamo";
            //Justo acá es donde necesito insertar mi tabla
            mail.Body = cuerpo;
            mail.To.Add(correo_electronico);
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Hace falta saber cómo es el Datatable, ya que para hacer la Tabla HTML es necesario saber cuántas columnas y filas tienes. En si el código no es más difícil que hacer bucles que recorran el Datatable y vayan escribiendo todas las etiquetas HTML necesarias `<td> <tr> <table> `etc

Comment: @AgustinM. 
El datatable que tengo tiene 5 columnas, _Id_equipo, Nombre_equipo, Marca_equipo, Serial_equipo, Codigo_de_barras_
Y las filas pueden variar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el cuerpo debe ir un string. Asi que debes recorrer los datos e ir concatenando. Es decir, algo así.

```
String tabla="<table>
foreach (Dato in datos)
   tabla+="<tr>"+dato+"</tr>";
```

y luego

```
mail.Body =tabla
```